# awk error "makes too many open files"

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I have a awk based splitter that splits a huge file based on regex. But the problem is that I am getting a makes too many files error. Even i have a conditional close. If you could help me figure out what I am doing wrong I would be much grateful.

```
    awk 'BEGIN { system("mkdir -p splitted/sub"++j) }
    /<doc/{x="F"++i".xml";}{
     if (i%5==0 ){
       ++i;
       close("splitted/sub"j"/"x);
       system("mkdir -p splitted/sub"++j"/");
      }
     else{
       print > ("splitted/sub"j"/"x);
     }
    }' wiki_parsed.xml
```

Comment: Cant you just use `csplit`?

Comment: I tried using csplit but the recursive directory creation was not possible to my knowledge using csplit. So i opted for awk.

Comment: Not good to use awk in this case. There are full of pure shell commands in your awk command. write in shell script directly

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that close isn't being called often enough.  Here's an illustrative example of why:

Using an input file like:

```
<doc somestuff
another line
yet another line
<doc the second
still more data
<doc the third
<doc the fourth
<doc the fifth
```

I can make an executable awk file based on your script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { system_(++j) }

/<doc/{x=++i}

{
    if (i%5==0 ){ ++i; close_(j"/"x); system_(++j) }
    else{ open_(j"/"x) }
}

function call_f(funcname, arg) { print funcname"("arg")" }

function system_(cnt) { call_f( "system", cnt ) }
function open_(f) { if( !(f in a) ) { call_f( "open", f ); a[f]++ } }
function close_(f) { call_f( "close", f ) }
```

which if I put into a file called `awko` can be run like `awko data` to produce the following:

```
system(1)
open(1/1)
open(1/2)
open(1/3)
open(1/4)
close(1/5)
system(2)
```

The script I made is just indicating how many times you're calling each function by shadowing a real function call with a local function with a trailing `_`.  Notice how many times `open()` is printed compared to `close()` for the same arguments.  Also, I ended up renaming `print >` to `open_` just to illustrated that it's what's opening the files( once per file name ).

If I change the executable awk file to the following, you can see close being called enough:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { system_(++j) }

/<doc/{ close_(j"/"x); x=++i } # close_() call is moved to here.

{
    if (i%5==0 ){ ++i; system_(++j) }
    else{ open_(j"/"x) }
}

function call_f(funcname, arg) { print funcname"("arg")" }

function system_(cnt) { call_f( "system", cnt ) }
function open_(f) { if( !(f in a) ) { call_f( "open", f ); a[f]++ } }
function close_(f) { call_f( "close", f ) }
```

which gives the following output:

```
system(1)
close(1/)
open(1/1)
close(1/1)
open(1/2)
close(1/2)
open(1/3)
close(1/3)
open(1/4)
close(1/4)
system(2)
```

where it should be clear that `close()` is being called one more time than enough.  The first time it's being called on a file that doesn't exist.  With a true `close()` call, the fact that such a file has never been printed should just be ignored and no actual close will be attempted.  In each other case, the last `open()` matches a `close()` call.

Moving your `close()` call in your script as in the second example script should fix your error.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i got it to be working perfectly

```
    awk 'BEGIN { system("mkdir -p splitted/sub"++j) }
     /<doc/{x="F"++i".xml";}{

      if (i%1995==0 ){
       ++i;
       system("mkdir -p splitted/sub"++j"/");
      }
      else{
       print >> ("splitted/sub"j"/"x);
       close("splitted/sub"j"/"x);
      }

     }' wiki_parsed.xml
```